# Pulling down a specific tag of a git repository

Tags: git, github, deploying

I am using a system that, during high load, automatically fires up a new server, downloads the application code from Github, and deploys an HTTP server. However, I don't want to pull the latest commit from the master branch of the repo, but rather the latest tagged commit. Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, no; but how about having a 'deploy' branch which always contains the code you want to deploy? Work on the master as usual, but whenever the code is in a stable state push to 'deploy'.

Comment: Thank you. This is what we went with!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is fetch just the latest tags. If that is the case, then you can do it with git-fetch:

```
get fetch -t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git describe` to get the "nearest" name of a tag, then check out that tag after parsing the markup away.

```
git describe --long | sed 's/-[0-9]*-g[a-f0-9]*//'
```

You may want to use --tags as an argument to git-describe, depending on your needs.

Comment: +1 Nice one! However, this must be combined with git fetch so the latest tags are updated, unless the repo is always being cloned.

Comment: @Magnus: Well, reading between the lines, the OP deployed experimental code and wants the system to auto-rollback to a known good (tagged) state.  So fetching is probably not needed in this instance.